# How RADIUS server knows whether client requested for PAP authentication or CHAP authentication?

Tags: authentication, radius

I am trying to add authentication options pap, chap and mschapv1 and mschapv2 in radius client.

But I am not able to figure-out how RADIUS server finds out whether RADIUS client is requesting for pap or chap or mschapv1 or mschapv2. How does RADIUS server knows whether to send Challenge message or not (as in PAP we don't send Challenge message but in CHAP we do)?

Does client send auth-type while authentication? If yes, what auth-type is sent for pap, chap, mschapv1 or mschapv2?